# Plural usage of "function"

Tags: grammatical-number, subject-verb-agreement

I always get confused about how to build sentences like these:

1. What is their function?
2. What is their functions?
3. What are their functions?
4. What are their function?

I think the last one sounds weird. Which one is correct, and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With *What* questions, the verb must have the same number as the following noun or noun phrase, so the two correct versions are the first and the third:

> ***What is their function?*** ... Here you are asking about one function and must use *is*.
>
> ***What are their functions?***  ... Here you are asking about multiple functions and must use *are*.

Think about the answer you will get—the question must use the same verb:

> *Their function **is** this ...*
>
> *Their functions **are** these ...*

What may be confusing you is the plural *their*, which implies that you are asking about the function or functions of multiple things. Which of these two questions you ask will depend on the context:

> ***What is their function?*** ... Here you are looking at several tools or officials or rules or whatever and assuming that they all have the ***same function***, so you ask about a singular *function*.
>
> ***What are their functions?***  ... Here you are looking at several tools or officials or rules and assuming that each has a different function, so you ask about plural *functions*.

Likewise, you may use these same to forms with just a single thing:

> ***What is its function?*** ... Here you are looking at one thing and assuming it has only one function.
>
> ***What are its functions?*** ... Here you are looking at one thing and assuming it has multiple functions.